# Looping through an array of arrays (creating a dynamic table)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, html-table, tcpdf

I'm trying to create a dynamic table for a TCPDF document but looping through the query result is pretty uncomfortable.

[image: This is what I'm trying to get]

**$arrResult** variable that holds the SQL query looks like this:

```
array(1) { 
    ["Dec"]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> array(2) { 
                ["name"]=> string(4) "Jane" 
                ["message"]=> string(0) "test" 
            } 
        } 
        [1]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> array(2) { 
                ["name"]=> string(6) "Oliver" 
                ["message"]=> string(20) "test!" 
            } 
        } 
        [2]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> array(2) { 
                ["name"]=> string(4) "John" 
                ["message"]=> string(4) "test" 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I managed to loop the big array and get each Month but idk how to get the other data into the table. This is that part of the code:

```
$content = '';
     $content .= '<table border="1" cellpadding="1">';

        foreach($arrResults as $key=>$value) {
            $content .= "<tr><th style='font-weight:bold;font-size:12px' colspan='8' align='center'>".$key."</th></tr>";
                foreach($arrResults[$key] as $key2=>value2) {

                }
        }  

      $content .= '</table>';
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you see the answers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $content = '';
 $content .= '<table border="1" cellpadding="1">';

    foreach($arrResults as $key=>$value) {
        $content .= "<tr><th style='font-weight:bold;font-size:12px' colspan='8' align='center'>".$key."</th></tr>";
        $content .= "<tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>num</th>
                <th>prenum</th>
                <th>email</th>
                <th>rol</th>
                <th>data</th>
                <th>mesaj</th>
                <th>statue</th>
                </tr>";
            foreach($value as $key2=>$value2) 
            {
                $content .= '<tr><td>'.$key2.'</td>';
                foreach($value2 as $key3=>$value3) 
                {
                    $content .= '<td>'.$value3['num'].'</td>';
                    $content .= '<td>'.$value3['prenum'].'</td>';
                    $content .= '<td>'.$value3['email'].'</td>';
                    $content .= '<td>'.$value3['rol'].'</td>';
                    $content .= '<td>'.$value3['data'].'</td>';
                    $content .= '<td>'.$value3['mesaj'].'</td>';
                    $content .= '<td>'.$value3['statue'].'</td>';
                }
            $content .= '</tr>';
            }
    }  

  $content .= '</table>';
```

i think you want somethink like his, i have surely did some mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers!

It works now with this approach:

```
$content = '';  
$content .= '<table border="1" cellpadding="1">';

foreach($arrResults as $key=>$value) {
     $content .= '<tr><th style="font-weight:bold;font-size:12px" colspan="8" align="center">'. $key .'</th></tr>';
     $content .= '<tr>
              <th style="font-weight:bold;font-size:12px">ID</th>
              <th style="font-weight:bold;font-size:12px">Nume</th>
              <th style="font-weight:bold;font-size:12px">Prenume</th>
              <th style="font-weight:bold;font-size:12px">Email</th>
              <th style="font-weight:bold;font-size:12px">Rol</th>
              <th style="font-weight:bold;font-size:12px">Data Programare</th>
              <th style="font-weight:bold;font-size:12px">Mesaj</th>
              <th style="font-weight:bold;font-size:12px">Status</th>
           </tr>';
         foreach($value as $k => $v) {
         //var_dump($v);die();
            $content .= '<tr>';
            $content .= '<td>'. $v[0]['id'] .'</td>';
            $content .= '<td>'. $v[0]['last_name'] .'</td>';
            $content .= '<td>'. $v[0]['first_name'] .'</td>';
            $content .= '<td>'. $v[0]['email'] .'</td>';
            $content .= '<td>'. $v[0]['role'] .'</td>';
            $content .= '<td>'. $v[0]['appointment_date'] .'</td>';
            $content .= '<td>'. $v[0]['message'] .'</td>';
            $content .= '<td>'. $v[0]['status'] .'</td>';
            $content .= '</tr>';
         }
}
$content .= '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$contentdata = '';
$contentdata .='<table>';
$contentdata .='<tr>';
$contentdata .='<td><b>Decembire</b></td>';
$contentdata .='</tr>';
$contentdata .='<tr>';
$contentdata .='<td><span>ID</span></td>';
$contentdata .='<td><span>Nume</span></td>';
$contentdata .='<td><span>Prenume</span></td>';
$contentdata .='<td><span>Email</span></td>';
$contentdata .='<td><span>Roll</span></td>';
$contentdata .='<td><span>Data Programme</span></td>';
$contentdata .='<td><span>Mesaj</span></td>';
$contentdata .='<td><span>Status</span></td>';
$contentdata .='</tr>';

foreach($test['Dec'] as $key=>$value){
    $contentdata .= '<tr><td>'.$key.'</td>';
    foreach($value as $key1=>$valuedata){
        $contentdata .='<td><span>'.$valuedata['num'].'</span></td>';
        $contentdata .='<td><span>'.$valuedata['prenum'].'</span></td>';
        $contentdata .='<td><span>'.$valuedata['email'].'</span></td>';
        $contentdata .='<td><span>'.$valuedata['rol'].'</span></td>';
        $contentdata .='<td><span>'.$valuedata['data'].'</span></td>';
        $contentdata .='<td><span>'.$valuedata['mesaj'].'</span></td>';
        $contentdata .='<td><span>'.$valuedata['statue'].'</span></td>';
    }
    $contentdata .='</tr>';
}
echo $contentdata;
?>
```